# jmeter class not found

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run apache jmeter on my VM but getting this error.

```
D:\Users\1255592\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin>jmeter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConversionException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:257)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
JMeter home directory was detected as: 
D:\Users\1255592\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1
```

I am using java 1.7

Comment: full contents of *jmeter.log* file, please

Comment: i am not able to start jmeter application
not even getting any jmeter.log file

Comment: @GeetaDholwade Check your plugins, it's like you are missing some...

Comment: Some jar file(s) are missing in your VM. You may need to reinstall JMeter and its plugins.

Comment: I suggest reinstalling jmeter, and on proper location too, e.g. c:\jmeter (not on desktop). Could be for example lack of permissions, or class path too long, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation of JMeter is corrupt as the message here tells you that a class of xstream which is embedded as part of jmeter in lib folder is missing.

- com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException

So reinstall your version and ensure you unzip in a folder that you own.